# Sending javascript in response

Tags: javascript

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

     res.sendFile('index.html');

});
```

How do i send a javascript file along with index.html back to the client browser for rendering?

Comment: Well, I bet you know that all .html files can contain `script` tags inside. Why won't you just include it?

Comment: Could be a better way to do it

Comment: What's the point of reinventing the bicycle? This is pretty efficient way

Comment: The wheel comes before the bicycle

Comment: Woooow... So what?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send 2 responses, but you could embed your javascript in your index.html file!

Answer (score 0):

The index.html file should contain a reference to the js file in a <script> tag.

You only send the .html.

The browser parses it, sees the reference to the .js file and requests it then.

Answer (score 0):

> you can try this

```
 getOptions = (id) => {
      return  {
        root: `uploads/${id}'    // specify the path and file Name from where you want to send file
        dotfiles: 'deny',
      }

   }

     res.sendFile(id, getOptions(req.body.id));
```